# Moving Skype History from machine to machine

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a way to copy my skype chat history to another machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

Call and IM history is stored in `%appdata%\Skype` folder, which is usually at

```
C:\Users\your_windows_username\AppData\Roaming\Skype\your_skype_name\main.db
```

Make sure that Skype is not running.

1. In the Start Menu in the Search/Run box type `%appdata%\skype` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the OK. This will open Skype folder.
2. Locate a subfolder with name corresponding to your Skype name and open it. There will be a file with name `main.db` or just `main` if your PC is setup to not show extensions for known file types but you will still see description `Data Base File` in the Type column.
3. Copy this `main.db` file to you new computer in the Skype/username folder.